# How do I set default props for a component wrapped in a Raley container?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I have a component wrapped in a Relay container:

```
const Widget = (props) => {
  return (
   <div> { props.foo.bar } </div>
  )
}

Widget.defaultProps = { foo: {bar: 0} }

export default Relay.createContainer(Widget, {
  fragments: {
     store: () => Relay.QL`
       fragment on WidgetData {
          foo {
             bar
          }
        }
        `
   }
})
```

I'm using a GraphQL-as-a-service provider for a backend, and when the `foo` property of `WidgetData` isn't present, it returns `null`, which throws when my component attempts to render `props.null.bar`

As far as I know, `defaultProps` only works when the prop is `undefined`, not when it's `null`.

How can I protect against `null` results with `defaultProps` in this case?

Hoping to avoid writing a guard statement for each `prop` I reference, if possible.

Comment: could just manually override the constructor:

`const bar = props.foo || 'default'` and 

`<div> { bar } </div>`

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing now, but it can get pretty tedious with a lot of/deeply nested props. `defaultProps` feels a lot better of a fit, esp. since i'm already defining my `prop` shape for `propTypes`

Comment: I’ve worked around it by moving the Relay queries up to the containing component and passing in the result. This way I don’t use Relay at the level where I want to use `defaultProps`. This may not be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sanity check for props from Relay container.

```
render() {
  let {
    foo,
    ...other
  } = this.props;   
  let bar = foo ? foo.bar : '';
  return (
    <div> { bar } </div>
  )
}
```

For more info, checkout: https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery